# I18n.t falls back to key instead to default locale

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-i18n

In my frontend non-translated strings are replaced with word form of their key instead of the translation of base language.

That means that changing locale to :en or :tr both shows *Summaries Header* for `t('activerecord.misc.badge.summaries_header')` instead of *Auswertungen* from German locale. So it's obviously build from the last part of the key. *Summaries Header* does not appear as Label in any locale.

Other in :en/:tr translated strings are shown correctly.

```rb
# config/application.rb

config.i18n.default_locale = :de
config.i18n.available_locales = [
  :de, # Deutsch
  :pt, # Portugiesisch
  :en, # Englisch
  :tr, # Türkisch
]
config.i18n.fallbacks = true
```

```
# Versions
ruby 2.7.2
rails 5.2.4.4
i18n 1.8.6
rails-i18n 5.1.3
```

I can't find the reason for that behavior and I can't figure out which update at which time broke this.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Update to i18n v1.8.7 or higher with `bundle update i18n`

i18n v1.8.6 was broken regarding getting fallbacks from `config.i18n.*` into Thread variables.

See [i18n issue #546](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/issues/546) and [changelog for v1.8.7](https://github.com/ruby-i18n/i18n/releases/tag/v1.8.7)